# How to get the ARPointCloud counts from the depth camera on the front of iPhone X

Tags: arkit, depth, truedepth-camera

when i use the code
session.currentFrame?.rawFeaturePoints?.points.count
to get the point cloud data from the depth camera on the front of iPhone X，but，it turns out to be nil
Does anyone knows what I am missing？
I don’t know how to do it. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

The ARPointCloud is a set of points a representing intermediate results of the scene analysis ARKit uses to perform world tracking. Since the front camera of the iPhone X only supports face tracking, and not world tracking, maybe that's the reason you are getting nil.
Have you tried the back camera?

Answer (score 1):

> Feature point detection requires a ARWorldTrackingConfiguration session.

quoted from apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2887449-rawfeaturepoints).

You will not be able to get feature points from front camera.

If you still want to use front camera to get the depth data use this.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2928208-captureddepthdata

I hope it helps.